# Multiply all integers in a string by value in Python

Tags: python, regex, string, split

I need to multiply every integer in a string by another number, such that

```
In [1]: mystring = '2 apple trees yield 4 apples'
In [2]: myfunction(mystring, by = 2)

Out[3]:'4 apple trees yield 8 apples'
```

With a string like that, it isn't so bad to use regex reassemble the desired output but I would like to be able to handle this situation:

```
In [1]: mystring = '(((((A:1,B:1):1,C:2):2,D:4):2,(((E:1,F:1):1,G:2):2,H:4):2):2,(((I:1,J:1):1,K:2):2,L:4):4):8;'
In [2]: myfunction(mystring, by = 0.5)

Out[3]:'(((((A:0.5,B:0.5):0.5,C:1):1,D:2):1,(((E:0.5,F:0.5):0.5,G:1):1,H:2):1):1,(((I:0.5,J:0.5):0.5,K:1):1,L:2):2):4;'
```

Comment: is this homework ?

Comment: Where is your code and what problem are you having with it?

Comment: No, I'm simulating bifurcating trees, which are often represented in newick format (the second 'mystring'), and need to produce varying branch lengths between nodes (the numbers associated with node labels) while leaving the topology (everything that isn't a node label or branch length) alone.

Comment: Split the string by `'(\d)+'`, collect the list of fragments. `findall()` numbers in the original string using the same re, convert each fragment to int, multiply, convert back to str (use list comprehension). Now, zip both lists and flatten the result.

Comment: You have a string representation of an actual data structure. Parse it, define and apply an appropriate mapping function to the result, then re-encode that to a new string.

Comment: See [this demo](http://ideone.com/kLMzHl), you may use a more sophisticated logic in the lambda or a callback method.

Answer (score 4):

You can use [re.sub](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.sub) to replace all the integers.

```
def myfunction(mystring, by):
    return re.sub(
        re.compile("\d+"), 
        lambda matchobj: str(int(matchobj.group(0))*by), 
        mystring
        )

mystring = "(((((A:1,B:1):1,C:2):2,D:4):2,(((E:1,F:1):1,G:2):2,H:4):2):2,(((I:1,J:1):1,K:2):2,L:4):4):8;"
myfunction(mystring, by = 0.5)
'(((((A:0.5,B:0.5):0.5,C:1.0):1.0,D:2.0):1.0,(((E:0.5,F:0.5):0.5,G:1.0):1.0,H:2.0):1.0):1.0,(((I:0.5,J:0.5):0.5,K:1.0):1.0,L:2.0):2.0):4.0;'
```

Comment: See, you have `C:1.0` while OP expects `C:1`.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew both are the same number, that should not be a problem

Comment: Either works and a fully generalized method, like the above, that can return floats is better than just ints for my specific use.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `itertools.groupby`:

```
from itertools import groupby

mystring = '(((((A:12,B:1):1,C:2...H:4):2):2'
multiplier = 5

groups = []
for is_digit, g in groupby(mystring, lambda x: x.isdigit()):
    group = ''.join(g)
    if is_digit:
        group = str(int(group) * multiplier)
    groups.append(group)

multiplied = ''.join(groups)
print(multiplied)

#(((((A:24,B:2):2,C:4):4,D:8):4
```

Comment: this produces another (incorrect) result on my computer. Are you sure this works correctly?

Comment: I just ran it again... Did you use a different string? I tried with a few different ones, and always get correct results.

Comment: maybe he mean that your sample program and your sample output don't match, otherwise this work as expected