# How to multiply numbers that are in the string format?

Tags: python

I have a list, I need to be able to convert the numbers to a form that can be multiplied by user input.

```
my_list = {'key_lime_pie': ['eggs 20', 'crust 20', ' limes 28']}
```

so if I type in `3` I would expect it to get 60 eggs, 60 crust and 84 limes.

Comment: How you manipulate strings or convert between strings and numbers depends on the programming language. Tag your question with the language you're using.

Comment: Does [this answer your question?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43400211/1389394). This uses lamba.

Answer (score 0):

You need to prompt for user input. Then you need to iterate over the ingredients. Split each ingredient into its name and value. Apply the multiplier. Print the result:

```
my_list = {
    'key_lime_pie': ['eggs 20', 'crust 20', ' limes 28']
}

multiplier = int(input('Please enter a multiplier: '))

for k, v in my_list.items():
    print(k)
    for ingredient in v:
        name, value = ingredient.split()
        r = int(value) * multiplier
        print(f'\t{r} {name}')
```

**Console:**

```
Please enter a multiplier: 3
key_lime_pie
  60 eggs
  60 crust
  84 limes
```

Comment: Please encourage the new users to search the site for available potential/nearly exact questions/answers ^^